# Can't ignore line-length despite .codeclimate.yaml file

Tags: yaml, code-climate

I'm using Python Black to automatically reduce line length to 88 but the pep8 linter enforces a 79 character limit. I want to turn this off

My `.codeclimate.yaml` file starts with:

```yaml
engines:
  pep8:
    enabled: true
    checks:
      E501: # Line length checks
        enabled: false
```

but this doesn't seem to be respected.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.codeclimate.com/docs/advanced-configuration states that

> As an alternative to the configurations available in your repository's Settings page, you can choose to commit a `.codeclimate.yml` or `.codeclimate.json` configuration file.

The filename is wrong: it should end `.yml` not `.yaml`.